# How to implement rate limit in apache james 3.8 spring version

Tags: rate-limiting, ip-blocking, apache-james

I am new to apache james and trying to use james v3.8 spring version, can anyone help on how to implement a rate limit where I can set a max number of emails (say 100) per hour and if there are more than that then gets rejected.
Also is there a way to block an IP/user-emailId from sending emails/spam emails like say an user automatically sending 1000's of emails. So with this blocking config I can restrict a IP/user-emailId sending not more than 50 emails in a day and if more than 50 emails are sent then those emails will be blocked.
Please let me know how can the above 2 be achieved. Please let me know which config file and what settings to be made. Please help.

I tried looking into mailetContainer.xml file for any settings and even referred the smtpserver.xml files in the /conf directory but not able to get on how to achieve the 2 requirements.